# Inappropriate warning haunting my answer entry field: "Provide a complete example to reproduce your SQL question"

Tags: bug, answers, user-interface, posting, warning-message

I decided to necropost on [this Off-topic: Cannot reproduce question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12170150/2943403) in an attempt to steer researchers away from the accepted answer.  I would normally vote to close, but because I don't have a hammer that allows me to close questions that are off-topic AND because I am irritated when my votes on old / low-traffic questions fade away AND because the CloseVoteReviewers require recent activity, I am confident that my vote would be useless.

To my surprise, as I constructed my answer, a warning perpetually haunted my text field:

> Provide a complete example to reproduce your SQL question [...]

**But I am not posting a question, I am posting an answer ...and the schema is dictated in the OP's question.**

> [image]

Even after I added the schema as sql, the warning persisted (but obviously, adding the schema to my answer is needless noise).

> [image]

This is definitely striking me as buggy behavior.

Comment: And also I'm curious why SO seems to be promoting SQLFiddle[.com]; there are plenty of equally deserving fiddle sites out there (some perhaps more so because they're more capable, actively maintained, don't crash so much, work on mobile ...)

Comment: @Caius I don't think SE is promoting SQL Fiddle. It's just a remnant on the warning message to a site that was very popular (perhaps the only one) at that time.

Comment: @CaiusJard It mentions SQL Fiddle because the answer has a link to SQL Fiddle. It is not promoting it. On the contrary, it says you need to have the examples in the post itself instead of having it in SQL Fiddle. That link is probably the whole reason behind that warning.

Comment: So if link [6] had been http://db-fiddle.com it would have parsed it and said "DB Fiddle is useful..." ?

Comment: @Samuel I cannot add the [tag:status-review] tag.